# Invalid Credentials. Make sure you have provided the correct security credentials After apply SSL to domain

Tags: api, openssl, wso2, wso2-api-manager, invalidation

After applying vlid SSL to domain in wso2 APIM. We are using valid SSL

1. my devloper portal work fine its send response
   but in case of
2. Publisher side  when using try out
   I got following error while access API
   {
   "code": "900901",
   "message": "Invalid Credentials",
   "description": "Invalid Credentials. Make sure you have provided the correct security credentials"
   }

By Looking into jwt token

AT Publiher side :
"iss": "https://domain_name.com:9443/oauth2/token",

At Devloper side :
"iss": "https://IP_machine:9443/oauth2/token"

Comment: Do you see any error logs in the server?

Comment: ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.authenticator.InternalAPIKeyAuthenticator} - Invalid Internal Key.XXXXXUlMyNTYifQ